# Diminishing interest rate equation

Tags: limits

Let's say I gift someone a $1000 car

They have to pay 10% gift tax to keep it.

But if I gift them that gift tax also, then I also have to pay the tax from that gift  tax aswell.

I want a formula for how this would workout.

it would be like

x:y
0: 1000
1: 1000 + .10(1000)
2: (1000 + .1(1000)) + .1((1000 + .1(1000) - 1000)   or ans + .1(incrimental increase)
3:  ans + .1(difference between y(2) and y(1)

etc etc...

Basically it will increase each time by .1% of the incremental increase, thus it will have a horizontal asymptote.

I'm trying to figure out how you would model this and figure out what the total price would be...

Comment: Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question. This will make your question more readable and will attract many more people to answer it.

Comment: It’s an infinite geometric series.

Answer (score 0):

If the tax is $T$, then the total gift is $1000+T$.  The tax is $10\%$ of the gift, so $$T=.1(1000+T)\implies T=\frac{100}{.9}$$